# Cannot upload file with ! in name using Rebol

Tags: rebol

Is there a way to circumvent this ?

Answer (score 9):

That's a bug in Rebol v2.x with the network protocols.  It is a valid URL! type.  Normally, you could do a trick like this:

```
>> type? http://user:pass@myserver/test%21file.txt
== url!
```

See, it's a valid URL!

```
>> read http://user:pass@rtibackup/test%21file.txt
** User Error: URL error: http://user:pass@rtibackup/test!file.txt
** Near: read http://user:pass@rtibackup/test!file.txt
```

Oops, the network protocols don't like that URL.

But in this case, it does work using the following convention (also useful for passwords that contain the @ symbol):

```
>> write [
    scheme: 'ftp
    user: "myusername"
    pass: "mypassword"
    host: "myserver"
    target: %test!file.txt
] {Test}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

If this is still a problem, it's probably the URL parsing code that's an issue. Specific characters are special, but not that many, and especially not "!".

There's a newer version of Rebol called R3. Check if it's still a problem there. If so, R3 is open source and can be fixed quickly.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Chat is definitely a [secondary system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-chat-now-live/) here, but hopefully you've found it entertaining at least!

Answer (score 2):

When I do this using .net I just remove the offending item. I've never used Rebol but perhaps something like this might work?

```
change find fileuploaded "!" ""
probe fileuploaded
```

Was looking at the information on this page: http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wchange.html

hope it helps or at least points you in the right direction.